# Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in getting objects from the database

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to retrieve json records from the database. On retrieving the GET request over the browser my json responce is of this structure and returning appropriate data

```
[{"name":"OOGOGOGO","address":"OPOPOPOP","gender":"OPOPOPOP","email":"OPOPOPOP","phonenumber":"OPOPOPOP","nationality":"OPOOPOPO","fk":1}]
```

I am calling the endpoint url in the assync task doinbackground and this is the endpoint

```
url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:88/example/web/app_dev.php/get/1");
```

the above endpoint returns 405 status code error. On attempting to catch a json exception I get this error

```
error gotten org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted
```

confused on what could be wrong with this endpoint as it returns a 200 ok json response from postman. Kindly assist

Comment: What method do you used to deserialize the JSON data?

Comment: I just initialized this 
HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;
in assyntack before calling the endpoint

Comment: From you network response you need to create JSONObject. Eg: new JSONObject("Your network response string") or JSONArray.

Comment: please show snippet

Comment: but u ve to get a status code of 200 before creating a json object or json array which I already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code snippet.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Fetch network data
    new NetworkAsyncTask().execute("http://www.mocky.io/v2/591f32f4110000d10307b4c7");
}

private class NetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Success! Result: " + result);
            processResult(result);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed, no data");
        }
    }

    private void processResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject nameObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String name = nameObject.optString("name");
            Log.d("TAG", "name: " + name);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

For more information on networking and JSON on Android, i suggest you read this guide:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sending-and-Managing-Network-Requests
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Converting-JSON-to-Models

Comment: what about the progress dialog

Comment: You can create the progress dialog before calling the network and stop it when get the result.